# ant install via npm - requires node 0.8.0+ but fails to install?

Tags: java, windows, node.js, ant

I'm attempting to install Apache Ant via npm, however the install fails with the following message;

`npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ant
 npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ant
npm WARN engine ant@0.2.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.8.0"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.2" ,"npm":"1.2.15"})
ant@0.2.0 C:\Users\yousef\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ant`

The related package docs state that node 0.8+ is a requirement, and I have v0.10.2, so I'm wondering if this is simply a compatibility issue as it was authored over 2 years ago, or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

https://www.npmjs.org/package/ant

Any help would be appreciated :)

(Running Windows 7 x64)

Answer (score 2):

This is only a warning. Ant should still have installed successfully.

Comment: if its installed correctly, where will it be ?!  I have exactly same warning message as OP, but I can't find *any* new folder that has been created .. confused!  thanks

Comment: /usr/local/bin/ant I think. That's where it is on my machine (Mac OS)

Comment: The very last line returned from the install command tells you the path where it was installed, from the question above: `ant@0.2.0 C:\Users\yousef\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ant`

Answer (score 1):

This is only a warning. installation is done. but you have to add path of ant.bat in system environment variable.
I faced same error and resolved after adding system variable.